# mySQL queries are executed twice on wordpress website

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm sorry for my english.
I'm trying to add some functionalities at my Wordpress website and to do this i have added a function in my function.php theme. The idea is to save in a custom table some datas and create a wp_post for any element added in the custom table.

I hooked the function in this way:

```
add_action ( 'init', 'inserimentoAutoDatabase' );
```

The problem is that when the function is executed the query that save the datas in the custom table and create a new post is executed twice. I report my code:

```
function inserimentoAutoDatabase(){

//get datas from an xml file
$result = fetchData("http://dealer.drivek.it/myPortalXML/index?myPortalXMLkey=d660d1e9-8c1d-41ff-8f54-0829777a9960");

//save the xml  
$fp = fopen('autodealerk-1.xml', 'w+');
fwrite($fp, $result);
fclose($fp);

//load xml file
$xml=simplexml_load_file("autodealerk-1.xml");

$i=0;

//start parsing xml content
foreach($xml->car as $auto)
{
    //this echo is executed only once
    echo ("test");

    //not important for the question | checks some content
    if($auto->km == null || $auto->km  == ''){
        $kilometri = "nuova";
        $anno_registrazione = "-";
    }else{
        $kilometri = $auto->km;
        $anno_registrazione = $auto->registrationDate;
    }

    $inevidenza = 0;
    if($auto->tractionType){
        $inevidenza = 1;
    }


    // create an array for the query
    $insData = array(
        'id' => $auto['id'],
        'make' => (string) $auto->make,
        'model' => (string) $auto->model,
        'version' => (string) $auto->version,
        'bodyType' => $auto->bodyType,
        'fuelType' => $auto->fuelType,
        'type' => $auto->type,
        'dealer_name' => (string) $auto->dealer->name,
        'gear_gearType' => (string) $auto->gear->gearType,
        'tractionType' => $auto->tractionType,
        'kw' => $auto->kw,
        'doors' => $auto->doors,
        'seats' => $auto->seats,
        'emissionClass' => $auto->emissionClass,
        'prices_listPrices' => $auto->prices->listPrice,
        'exterior_color_paint' => $auto->exterior->color . " " . $auto->exterior->paint,
        'km' => $kilometri,
        'typewarrantyMonths' =>  $auto->warranty->type . " " . $auto->warranty->warrantyMonths,
        'equipments' => "equipaggiamenti",
        'media' => $auto->image,
        'description' => $auto->description,
        'registrationDate' => $anno_registrazione
    );

    $columns = implode("`, `",array_keys($insData));
    $escaped_values = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', array_values($insData));
    $values  = implode("', '", $escaped_values);

    //execute the query ******* the query is executed twice
    //i have replaced this line with the following *** read the comment below
    //mysql_query('INSERT INTO  `auto_importate` (`'.$columns.'`) VALUES (\''.$values.'\')');

    $wpdb->insert('auto_importate', $insData);


    // define the post
    $my_post = array(
      'post_title'    => (string) $auto->make . (string) $auto->model . (string) $auto->version,
      'post_content'  => $auto->description,
      'post_status'   => 'publish',
      'post_author'   => 1,
      'post_type'     => "vehicles"
    );

    // ***** post is created twice
    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );


    //i break the cycle **** only for test
    $i++;
    if( $i == 1 ) break;

}
}
```

As you can see in the images below at the end of the cicle (breaked after the first execution) i expect only one element but there are twice.

[image: auto_importate table]

[image: auto_importate table content]

Anyone can help me??? Have you any idea about this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please check  mysql_query and wp_insert_post. These two can work at same time will create two rows

Comment: Thanks to @user2384416 for the suggestion. I was looking to some conflicts between  mysql_query and wp_insert_post when i found this post [link](http://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/04/07/mysql-in-wordpress-3-9/) where there is written _absolutely shouldn’t be using PHP’s mysql_*() functions any more – you can use the equivalent WPDB functions instead_ . So i have tried to change mysql_query with $wpdb->insert but the issue is still present.

Comment: This function will run every time you open a page on your site, as it's hooked into the init hook, which runs on every page load. Just a heads up, I don't know if that was intedned or not. http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init

Comment: Thanks for your observation @CalvindeClaisse-Walford. The idea is execute this function once a day checking the data of the last post vehicle stored in the DB. I have to implement this functionality yet. Have you any idea to how implement this behavior in another way? i know about [wp_schedule_event](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event), could it be usefull?

Comment: @ManuelRagazzini I would highly recommend that, or set a transient DB entry that expires at a set interval, and then run the check again.  I would be careful to not bloat your database with duplicates of the same rows, though, so implementing some sort of check would be ideal.

Comment: @CalvindeClaisse-Walford thanks a lot for your help. Have any ideas about the issue of my code too?

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the duplicate entries using `wp_insert_post`, you can check the same name of the title already exists or not. If that is exist, then you can skip that insertion.

You should try this

```
if (!get_page_by_title($title, 'OBJECT', 'post') ){

 $my_post = array('post_title' => $title,
                         'post_content' => 'Content',
                         'tags_input' => $tags,
                         'post_category' => array(2),
                         'post_status' => 'publish'
                        );

  $result = wp_insert_post( $my_post );
}
```